# How to resolve TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of null(occurs because of native base tabs react native)?

Tags: react-native, native-base

**Issue Description:**

I am working on react native application and using "Native Base" tabs structure. It throws me an error and this occurs continuously after some time interval.

**Error::**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of null
>
> Unable to symbolicate stack trace: The stack is null

**Code::**

```
// class render function
    render() {
        const { showLoading } = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={[flex1]}>
                {(!showLoading) &&
                    <>
                        <Tabs renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab style={[styles.tabBar, bgWhite]} />}>
                            <Tab
                                heading="ComponentONE"
                                tabStyle={[tabStyle, bgWhite]}
                                activeTabStyle={[tabStyle, bgWhite]}
                                textStyle={[tabTextStyle, fs15, textGrey]}
                                activeTextStyle={[tabTextStyle, fs15, textPrimary]}
                            >
                                <ComponentONE key={this.props.key ? this.props.key : ''} />
                            </Tab>
                            <Tab
                                heading="ComponentTWO"
                                tabStyle={[tabStyle, bgWhite]}
                                activeTabStyle={[tabStyle, bgWhite]}
                                textStyle={[tabTextStyle, fs15, textGrey]}
                                activeTextStyle={[tabTextStyle, fs15, textPrimary]}
                            >
                                <ComponentTWO />
                            </Tab>
                            <Tab
                                heading="ComponentTHREE"
                                tabStyle={[tabStyle, bgWhite]}
                                activeTabStyle={[tabStyle, bgWhite]}
                                textStyle={[tabTextStyle, fs15, textGrey]}
                                activeTextStyle={[tabTextStyle, fs15, textPrimary]}
                            >
                                <ComponentTHREE/>
                            </Tab>
                        </Tabs>
                    </>
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Ive recently used the scrollable tabs of native base and it worked fine. I think there's something (probably loading state ) is causing this issue, could you edit and paste complete code here, coz with this snippet its pretty difficult to observe the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with native base and ideally they claim they have fixed it with this pull request :
[geeky ants pull](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/pull/2982)

Basically if you are using Tabs without any scrollView it throws an error of scrollTo of undefined , i recommend try once enclosing your whole TAB component inside a scrollView and check if it works.

CODE:

```
// class render function
    render() {
        const { showLoading } = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={[flex1]}>
                {(!showLoading) &&
                    <ScrollView>
                        <Tabs renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab style={[styles.tabBar, bgWhite]} />}>
                            <Tab
                                heading="ComponentONE"
                                tabStyle={[tabStyle, bgWhite]}
                                activeTabStyle={[tabStyle, bgWhite]}
                                textStyle={[tabTextStyle, fs15, textGrey]}
                                activeTextStyle={[tabTextStyle, fs15, textPrimary]}
                            >
                                <ComponentONE key={this.props.key ? this.props.key : ''} />
                            </Tab>
                            <Tab
                                heading="ComponentTWO"
                                tabStyle={[tabStyle, bgWhite]}
                                activeTabStyle={[tabStyle, bgWhite]}
                                textStyle={[tabTextStyle, fs15, textGrey]}
                                activeTextStyle={[tabTextStyle, fs15, textPrimary]}
                            >
                                <ComponentTWO />
                            </Tab>
                            <Tab
                                heading="ComponentTHREE"
                                tabStyle={[tabStyle, bgWhite]}
                                activeTabStyle={[tabStyle, bgWhite]}
                                textStyle={[tabTextStyle, fs15, textGrey]}
                                activeTextStyle={[tabTextStyle, fs15, textPrimary]}
                            >
                                <ComponentTHREE/>
                            </Tab>
                        </Tabs>
                    </ScrollView>
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts. coz ive used Tabs with scrollView of native base and it worked fine.

Comment: I have used ScrollView and also tried the code addition inside the native-base file but both of them are not working for me

Comment: after adding ScrollView I am getting new error:: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this.scrollView.scrollTo')`

Comment: Inserting `<Tabs>` between `<Scrollview>` didn't help. Fix is merged by Native-Base team to master but looks like not yet packeged to npm. You can use `npm install GeekyAnts/NativeBase#master` to use master branch but don't forget to lock it to some specific packege version once fix is there. @archana-sharma

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into this problem, another possible issue that I encountered was when using a conditional statement to render nativebase `<Tabs>` immediately after `<Header hasTabs>`. If one part of your condition doesn't actually contain a `<Tabs>` element, you will get an error saying `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_this.scrollView.scrollTo')`

To fix this, ensure that your conditional statement always returns a `<Tabs>` code block with whatever other content you want within that code block.

Alternatively, ensure your if condition goes outside the `<Header hasTabs>` code block.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed on https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/pull/2982. Temporarily install the latest NativeBase master until the next release:

`yarn add GeekyAnts/NativeBase#master`